# How to define boundary numbers without decimal points - Choropleth

Tags: python, matplotlib, choropleth, geopandas

**Problem**
The numbers in a legend has the decimal points (eg. 0.00-4.80), when I want them to be integers without decimal points.

**My current graph**
[Seoul city, showing poll rates area by area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUleG.jpg)

**My code**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xkcd()
seoul=gpd.read_file('../json/seoul_municipalities_geo.json')
# You can download the same file from the Github below
# https://github.com/southkorea/seoul-maps/tree/master/juso/2015/json

data_result.plot(figsize=(14,10),linewidth=0.25, edgecolor='black', column='ESRI_PK',cmap='Blues',scheme='quantiles',legend=True)

for index,row in seoul.iterrows():
    xy=row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    xytext=row['geometry'].centroid.coords[:]
    plt.annotate(row['SIG_ENG_NM'],xy=xy[0], xytext=xytext[0],  horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')
    plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, but `im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10,10)))` this kind of code does not seem to work with Choropleth map. I have used `data_result.plot()`, plot method, and I don't know how to change it to the way using **imshow method**....:/

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have changed my question completely so that you can now reproduce my problem to see what it is :D. Can you answer this question, please?

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? If you change `0 - 4.80` to `0 - 5` the color of a region with a quantity of 4.9 will be wrongly labelled, right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No, it won't be wrongly labelled. All I care is that the labels' boundary values are integers. It doesn't matter whether a certain region is labelled as the category A or B, if the categories are separated by the integer values. :)

Comment: What that means is that you do not actually want to change the legend entries, but the mapping inside the geopandas plot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What i want is to change the legend entries. I want to change the boundary values (located in the legend box on the top right corner) from decimals to integers. It's because I am making these maps for publishing articles after the election is over. It would be much easier for the newspaper readers to have the integer numbers in legend!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest When the boundary values are integers, I hope the regions to be categorized to boundaries in legend accordingly. To sum up, the values of boundaries come first. They need to be integers. And then region categorization in the maps come second, and I hope the regions would be categorized to the boundaries (which are separated by integers) accordingly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have had tried to solve my problem and it seems that Geopandas library does not support any function providing more sophisticated options which I wanted..

Comment: Well it seems so, there are only [3 different scemes supported](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/ce8f70c80ef23261a48b268d06878f3d6968848f/geopandas/plotting.py#L520). However, I'm not sure what happens if you preprocess your data into the categoies you want. E.g. you map your data to a set of numbers, 0-5 -> 2.5, 5-10-> 7.5, etc. and do not specify any sceme at all. Then later you change the legend labels from 2.5 to 0 - 5, 7.5 to 5-10 etc. I did not try this but just looking at the source code this might be possible.